# C# - ASP.NET Issue with sending multiple data with Response.Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I have 2 Web Forms

```
Catalog.aspx
ViewItem.aspx
```

In `Catalog.aspx`, I have a `DataList` that is connected to my Database.
My database contains Item `Name`, `Image url` and `Price`.

I'm trying to send over these 3 values with `Response.Redirect`.

I found this code online that works well with sending over the Image url but I'm not sure how to add on more values to it

This is the code

```
Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx?ImageUrl=" + ((ImageButton)sender).ImageUrl);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: first you need to understand the format of a URL querystring, then it will become quite obvious. You can look up that online very easily.

Comment: If the only thing you are doing in the button click method is a redirect, why not make it a normal link? Save a PostBack, make a HyperLink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.
 you can append all the parameters and send along with redirect url

```
   var redirectParams= string.Format("ImageUrl={0}&Name={1}&Price={2}",((ImageButton)sender).ImageUrl, Name, Price);
   Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx?" + redirectParams);
```